# No me funciona mi chat 1 a 1

Tags: java, socket

Tengo que hacer un chat 1 a 1
Tengo que escribir en un cliente 1 a un cliente 2 que el mensaje lo reciba el servidor y lo envia al cliente 2 y al reves
Cuando ejecuto no me hace nada se me queda esperando los clientes y no se porque no me los acepta

Creo que el fallo me da porque el servidor no me acepta ningun cliente ya que no me sale ningun println que lo muetro con la funcion mostrarTexto

### Codigo Servidor

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class servidor {

    private ServerSocket servidor;
    private Socket cliente1;
    private Socket cliente2;
    private DataInputStream bufferDeEntradaCli1 = null;
    private DataOutputStream bufferDeSalidaCl1 = null;
    private DataInputStream bufferDeEntradaCli2 = null;
    private DataOutputStream bufferDeSalidaCl2 = null;
    Scanner escaner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void levantarConexion(int puerto) {
        try {
            servidor = new ServerSocket(puerto);
            mostrarTexto("Esperando conexión entrante en el puerto " + String.valueOf(puerto) + "...");
            
            // Aceptar la conexión del cliente 1
            cliente1 = servidor.accept();
            System.out.println(cliente1.getKeepAlive());
            mostrarTexto("Conexión establecida con: " + cliente1.getInetAddress().getHostName() + "\n\n\n");
            
            // Aceptar la conexión del cliente 2
            cliente2 = servidor.accept();
            mostrarTexto("Conexión establecida con: " + cliente2.getInetAddress().getHostName() + "\n\n\n");
            
            // Notificar a ambos clientes que la conexión se ha establecido
            enviarMensajeCli1("Conexion establecida con ambos clientes");
            enviarMensajeCli2("Conexion establecida con ambos clientes");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mostrarTexto("Error en levantarConexion(): " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void flujosCli1() {
        try {
            bufferDeEntradaCli1 = new DataInputStream(cliente1.getInputStream());
            bufferDeSalidaCl1 = new DataOutputStream(cliente1.getOutputStream());
            bufferDeSalidaCl1.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mostrarTexto("Error en la apertura de flujos");
        }
    }
    
    public void flujosCli2() {
        try {
            bufferDeEntradaCli2 = new DataInputStream(cliente2.getInputStream());
            bufferDeSalidaCl2 = new DataOutputStream(cliente2.getOutputStream());
            bufferDeSalidaCl2.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mostrarTexto("Error en la apertura de flujos");
        }
    }

    public void recibirDatosEnviarCli1() {
        String mensajeCli2 = "";
        try {
            do {
                mensajeCli2 = (String) bufferDeEntradaCli2.readUTF();
                mostrarTexto("\n[Cliente2] => " + mensajeCli2);
                enviarMensajeCli1(mensajeCli2);
            } while (!mensajeCli2.equalsIgnoreCase("QUIT"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            cerrarConexionCli1();
        }
    }
    
    public void recibirDatosEnviarCli2() {
        String mensajeCli1 = "";
        try {
            do {
                mensajeCli1 = (String) bufferDeEntradaCli1.readUTF();
                mostrarTexto("\n[Cliente1] => " + mensajeCli1);
                enviarMensajeCli2(mensajeCli1);
            } while (!mensajeCli1.equalsIgnoreCase("QUIT"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            cerrarConexionCli2();
        }
    }


    public void enviarMensajeCli1(String mensaje) {
        try {
            bufferDeSalidaCl1.writeUTF(mensaje);
            bufferDeSalidaCl1.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mostrarTexto("Error en enviar(): " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    public void enviarMensajeCli2(String mensaje) {
        try {
            bufferDeSalidaCl2.writeUTF(mensaje);
            bufferDeSalidaCl2.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mostrarTexto("Error en enviar(): " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void mostrarTexto(String s) {
        System.out.print(s);
    }


    public void cerrarConexionCli1() {
        try {
            bufferDeEntradaCli1.close();
            bufferDeSalidaCl1.close();
            cliente1.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          mostrarTexto("Excepción en cerrarConexion(): " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            mostrarTexto("Conversación finalizada....");

        }
    }
    
    public void cerrarConexionCli2() {
        try {
            bufferDeEntradaCli2.close();
            bufferDeSalidaCl2.close();
            cliente2.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          mostrarTexto("Excepción en cerrarConexion(): " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            mostrarTexto("Conversación finalizada....");

        }
    }

    public void ejecutarConexionCli1(int puerto) {
        Thread hilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    flujosCli1();
                    recibirDatosEnviarCli1();
                    
                } finally {
                    cerrarConexionCli1();
                }
            }
        });
        hilo.start();
    }

    public void ejecutarConexionCli2(int puerto) {
        Thread hilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    flujosCli2();
                    recibirDatosEnviarCli2();
                } finally {
                    cerrarConexionCli2();
                }
            }
        });
        hilo.start();
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        servidor servidor = new servidor();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int puerto = 51324;
        servidor.levantarConexion(puerto);
        servidor.ejecutarConexionCli1(puerto);
        servidor.ejecutarConexionCli2(puerto);
    }
}
```

### Codigo cliente

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cliente {
    private Socket servidor;
    private DataInputStream bufferDeEntrada = null;
    private DataOutputStream bufferDeSalida = null;
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    private InetAddress direccion;

    public void levantarConexion(int puerto) {
        try {
            byte addr[] = { (byte)192, (byte)168, (byte)0, (byte)10+1 };
            direccion = InetAddress.getByAddress( addr );
            servidor = new Socket(direccion, puerto);
            System.out.println("Conexión realizada con éxito");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mostrarTexto("Excepción al levantar conexión: " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void mostrarTexto(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public void abrirFlujos() {
        try {
            bufferDeEntrada = new DataInputStream(servidor.getInputStream());
            bufferDeSalida = new DataOutputStream(servidor.getOutputStream());
            bufferDeSalida.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mostrarTexto("Error en la apertura de flujos");
        }
    }

    public void enviar(String s) {
        try {
            bufferDeSalida.writeUTF(s);
            bufferDeSalida.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mostrarTexto("IOException on enviar");
        }
    }

    public void cerrarConexion() {
        try {
            bufferDeEntrada.close();
            bufferDeSalida.close();
            servidor.close();
            mostrarTexto("Conexión terminada");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mostrarTexto("IOException on cerrarConexion()");
        }finally{
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void ejecutarConexion(int puerto) {
        Thread hilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    abrirFlujos();
                    // Inicia el hilo para recibir datos del servidor
                    Thread recibirHilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            recibirDatos();
                        }
                    });
                    recibirHilo.start();
                    // Escribir datos mientras se reciben datos del servidor
                    escribirDatos();
                } finally {
                    cerrarConexion();
                }
            }
        });
        hilo.start();
    }

    public void recibirDatos() {
        String st = "";
        try {
            do {
                st = (String) bufferDeEntrada.readUTF();
                mostrarTexto("\n[Servidor] => " + st);
                System.out.print("\n[Usted] => ");
            } while (st.equalsIgnoreCase("QUIT"));
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }

    public void escribirDatos() {
        String entrada = "";
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("[Usted] => ");
            entrada = teclado.nextLine();
            if(entrada.length() > 0)
                enviar(entrada);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] argumentos) {
        cliente cliente = new cliente();
        Scanner escaner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int puerto=51324;
        cliente.levantarConexion(puerto);
        cliente.ejecutarConexion(puerto);
    }
}
```

---

Codigo cliente

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cliente {
    private Socket servidor;
    private DataInputStream bufferDeEntrada = null;
    private DataOutputStream bufferDeSalida = null;
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    private InetAddress direccion;

    public void levantarConexion(int puerto) {
        try {
            byte addr[] = { (byte)192, (byte)168, (byte)0, (byte)10+1 };
            direccion = InetAddress.getByAddress( addr );
            servidor = new Socket(direccion, puerto);
            System.out.println("Conexión realizada con éxito");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mostrarTexto("Excepción al levantar conexión: " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void mostrarTexto(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public void abrirFlujos() {
        try {
            bufferDeEntrada = new DataInputStream(servidor.getInputStream());
            bufferDeSalida = new DataOutputStream(servidor.getOutputStream());
            bufferDeSalida.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mostrarTexto("Error en la apertura de flujos");
        }
    }

    public void enviar(String s) {
        try {
            bufferDeSalida.writeUTF(s);
            bufferDeSalida.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mostrarTexto("IOException on enviar");
        }
    }

    public void cerrarConexion() {
        try {
            bufferDeEntrada.close();
            bufferDeSalida.close();
            servidor.close();
            mostrarTexto("Conexión terminada");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mostrarTexto("IOException on cerrarConexion()");
        }finally{
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void ejecutarConexion(int puerto) {
        Thread hilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    abrirFlujos();
                    // Inicia el hilo para recibir datos del servidor
                    Thread recibirHilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            recibirDatos();
                        }
                    });
                    recibirHilo.start();
                    // Escribir datos mientras se reciben datos del servidor
                    escribirDatos();
                } finally {
                    cerrarConexion();
                }
            }
        });
        hilo.start();
    }

    public void recibirDatos() {
        String st = "";
        try {
            do {
                st = (String) bufferDeEntrada.readUTF();
                mostrarTexto("\n[Servidor] => " + st);
                System.out.print("\n[Usted] => ");
            } while (st.equalsIgnoreCase("QUIT"));
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }

    public void escribirDatos() {
        String entrada = "";
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("[Usted] => ");
            entrada = teclado.nextLine();
            if(entrada.length() > 0)
                enviar(entrada);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] argumentos) {
        cliente cliente = new cliente();
        Scanner escaner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int puerto=51324;
        cliente.levantarConexion(puerto);
        cliente.ejecutarConexion(puerto);
    }
}
```

---

Codigo Servidor

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class servidor {

    private ServerSocket servidor;
    private Socket cliente1;
    private Socket cliente2;
    private DataInputStream bufferDeEntradaCli1 = null;
    private DataOutputStream bufferDeSalidaCl1 = null;
    private DataInputStream bufferDeEntradaCli2 = null;
    private DataOutputStream bufferDeSalidaCl2 = null;
    Scanner escaner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void levantarConexion(int puerto) {
        try {
            servidor = new ServerSocket(puerto);
            mostrarTexto("Esperando conexión entrante en el puerto " + String.valueOf(puerto) + "...");
            
            // Aceptar la conexión del cliente 1
            cliente1 = servidor.accept();
            System.out.println(cliente1.getKeepAlive());
            mostrarTexto("Conexión establecida con: " + cliente1.getInetAddress().getHostName() + "\n\n\n");
            
            // Aceptar la conexión del cliente 2
            cliente2 = servidor.accept();
            mostrarTexto("Conexión establecida con: " + cliente2.getInetAddress().getHostName() + "\n\n\n");
            
            // Notificar a ambos clientes que la conexión se ha establecido
            enviarMensajeCli1("Conexion establecida con ambos clientes");
            enviarMensajeCli2("Conexion establecida con ambos clientes");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mostrarTexto("Error en levantarConexion(): " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void flujosCli1() {
        try {
            bufferDeEntradaCli1 = new DataInputStream(cliente1.getInputStream());
            bufferDeSalidaCl1 = new DataOutputStream(cliente1.getOutputStream());
            bufferDeSalidaCl1.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mostrarTexto("Error en la apertura de flujos");
        }
    }
    
    public void flujosCli2() {
        try {
            bufferDeEntradaCli2 = new DataInputStream(cliente2.getInputStream());
            bufferDeSalidaCl2 = new DataOutputStream(cliente2.getOutputStream());
            bufferDeSalidaCl2.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mostrarTexto("Error en la apertura de flujos");
        }
    }

    public void recibirDatosEnviarCli1() {
        String mensajeCli2 = "";
        try {
            do {
                mensajeCli2 = (String) bufferDeEntradaCli2.readUTF();
                mostrarTexto("\n[Cliente2] => " + mensajeCli2);
                enviarMensajeCli1(mensajeCli2);
            } while (!mensajeCli2.equalsIgnoreCase("QUIT"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            cerrarConexionCli1();
        }
    }
    
    public void recibirDatosEnviarCli2() {
        String mensajeCli1 = "";
        try {
            do {
                mensajeCli1 = (String) bufferDeEntradaCli1.readUTF();
                mostrarTexto("\n[Cliente1] => " + mensajeCli1);
                enviarMensajeCli2(mensajeCli1);
            } while (!mensajeCli1.equalsIgnoreCase("QUIT"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            cerrarConexionCli2();
        }
    }


    public void enviarMensajeCli1(String mensaje) {
        try {
            bufferDeSalidaCl1.writeUTF(mensaje);
            bufferDeSalidaCl1.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mostrarTexto("Error en enviar(): " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    public void enviarMensajeCli2(String mensaje) {
        try {
            bufferDeSalidaCl2.writeUTF(mensaje);
            bufferDeSalidaCl2.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            mostrarTexto("Error en enviar(): " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void mostrarTexto(String s) {
        System.out.print(s);
    }


    public void cerrarConexionCli1() {
        try {
            bufferDeEntradaCli1.close();
            bufferDeSalidaCl1.close();
            cliente1.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          mostrarTexto("Excepción en cerrarConexion(): " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            mostrarTexto("Conversación finalizada....");

        }
    }
    
    public void cerrarConexionCli2() {
        try {
            bufferDeEntradaCli2.close();
            bufferDeSalidaCl2.close();
            cliente2.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          mostrarTexto("Excepción en cerrarConexion(): " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            mostrarTexto("Conversación finalizada....");

        }
    }

    public void ejecutarConexionCli1(int puerto) {
        Thread hilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    flujosCli1();
                    recibirDatosEnviarCli1();
                    
                } finally {
                    cerrarConexionCli1();
                }
            }
        });
        hilo.start();
    }

    public void ejecutarConexionCli2(int puerto) {
        Thread hilo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    flujosCli2();
                    recibirDatosEnviarCli2();
                } finally {
                    cerrarConexionCli2();
                }
            }
        });
        hilo.start();
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        servidor servidor = new servidor();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int puerto = 51324;
        servidor.levantarConexion(puerto);
        servidor.ejecutarConexionCli1(puerto);
        servidor.ejecutarConexionCli2(puerto);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Sí sabes que se debe agregar lo que se ha intentado e investigado en las preguntas?